# Which time is used for TOTP?

Tags: php, android, authentication

I'm trying to implement Time-based One-time Password to my web application, but I have some problems. I am testing it with Google's Android application "Google Authenticator", but I can't get the same code for succesfull login. After I studied the algorithm deeper, I saw, that time on server, should probably be the same as time in the phone. So I started to think about my server clock. Does it has to be users local time or is it the UTC or something similar. I can't find that anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it looks like the right answer is UTC time. After some deeper research I synchronized my server time with UTC and it started to work.

Answer (score 0):

The authentication app actually receives a time sync in the app itself. So It should be the same as google server time. It can use the local phone time however, so you should probably try to sync it again. This will not change your phone's time, it will only change the app's time correction.

To make sure that you have the correct time on your client (the phone):

1. Go to the main menu on the Google Authenticator app
2. Click **Settings**
3. Click **Time correction for codes**
4. Click **Sync now**

(source: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185834?hl=en#sync )

Comment: Well, yes I know that, but I don't know what is the google server time. If I click Sync, wich time does it syncs to?